# WPF C#, parse webbrowser content in htmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, html-agility-pack

I need to scrap some data from a website, I create a webbrowser to allow the user to make login and use the search tool and once he searched and got the list with the results I want to have the ability to get this data and perform further analysis and have offline access.

As I said the easiest approach for me is using a webbrowser, it works out of the box, login works, surfing works, and then when I reach the appropriated page I have the `webBrowser.Document` witch is a `mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass` (if I´m correct).
But htmlAgilityPack request a `HtmlDocument`

What's the easiest way to parse from one to the other? Please notice the webbroser is WPF webbrowser.

Answer (score 4):

No temporal extra files needed, just parsing from the right class.

```
string html = (webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument).documentElement.innerHTML;
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

from here on .. happy scrapping :)

Answer (score 1):

You may download the website as a string and store it in a temporary file and then load it into the `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument` class with

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
```

or directly from a stream:

```
doc.Load(iostream);
```

or more directly **from a string**:

```
doc.LoadHtml("<html>...</html>")
```

which i think may fit perfect in your case. I believe your webbrowsercontrol has a method to get the full source code.